# What is the formula for going along a certain fraction of the circumference of a circle?

Tags: trigonometry, modular-arithmetic

Say we have a circle with radius $1$, centered at the origin. If we want to start at the top of the circle and go clockwise along a certain proportion of the circumference, is there a formula for the $x$ and $y$ values that we would end up at?

I'm wondering about this because I am trying to visualize modular multiplicative inverses (mod some prime $p$) by drawing the numbers $1$ through $p-1$ along the circumference of a circle and then connecting inverses to each other with line segments.

Edit: I made the circle for $p=29$
[image: Modular Inverses of 29 Along a Circle]

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3720371/deeper-understand-of-cos-and-sin) and [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions)

Comment: If you were starting at the right-most extent of the circle and going counterclockwise, the position would be given by $(\cos x, \sin x)$.  Since you're starting at the top and moving clockwise, the position is given by $(\cos (\frac{\pi}{2}-x), \sin (\frac{\pi}{2}-x))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to parametrize a circumference counterclockwise starting from $(x,y)=(1,0)$ is as follows

- $x=\cos \theta$
- $y=\sin \theta$

for clockwise direction starting from $(x,y)=(0,1)$ we have

- $x=\cos \left(\frac \pi 2-\theta\right)=\sin \theta$
- $y=\sin \left(\frac \pi 2-\theta\right)=\cos \theta$

or using [tangent half-angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula) identities

- $x=\sin \theta=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$
- $y=\cos \theta=\frac{1.t^2}{1+t^2}$

with $t=\tan \frac \theta 2$.